# Can you build SSHD from SSD and HDD?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, ssd, merge

I have 1 SSD and 1 HDD. The SSD has 60GB of space and HDD has 1TB of space.

Is it possible to build an SSHD from it? I have herd is possible but if I search up this question it usually brings up normal SSHD.

My basic question: Is it possible to have SSD and HDD as 1 partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes and yes.**

Almost all modern RAID controllers offer SSD caching functionality - starting from even basic consumer ones.

Intel Smart Response Technology is one option. If your motherboard has an Intel RAID controller from the 7x generation or above you probably have it built in. The biggest limitation is that you can only use up to 64GB of SSD cache with Intel SRT - but that's not an issue for you with a 60GB SSD.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_Response_Technology

Third-party Marvell cards support more cache and operate in "hardware" with no size limitations. The following 4-port for example, allows 3 SSDs + 1 HDD:

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Syba-Marvell-HyperDuo-Support-Brackets/dp/B00AZ9T264

There are plenty more as well, these are just examples. Highpoint and LSI/Avago cards support it too, but they're more enterprise-orientated products. None of these of these actually require you to use RAID, they're just called RAID controllers because they share the core technology.

Comment: Yah my motherboard has ssd chase, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.

No: Without specialised tools and a **lot** of work you can not just just a single device which basically is a harddisk with an-onboard SSD used **by the SSHD's firmware** as a caching device.

Yes: If you move that caching to somewhere else, e.g. to the main computer then you can do so. Read up on [ZFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS) as an example for that. (The optional ARC part).

Note that this will not be a SSHD, but it can be the same functionality.

> My basic question: Is it possible to have SSD and HDD as 1 partition?

Yes. As with the example above, create a pool on the HDD and use that as a partition, then use ARC to cache for that.

Comment: Intel RST might be similar, though using a different mechanism. Apple also has the fusion drive thing. however it wouldn't be as simple or compact as an SSHD

Comment: I'll give it a try, I just want to have a fast loading times without filling my SSD with useless junk